# How to create dynamic contents with view

Tags: 7, views

I have to create some different pages in Drupal 7.
I need a different header and a custom text for the pages appearing in the same block, so I thought that it would be useful to create a view.
I did not develop that website, is it  the right way to do that?

I will explain it better.
I have to do 4 landing pages with the same structure.
I created a webform block for the right block. It will be the same on the four pages. Now I want to create two more blocks, one for the header and the other one for the text. I'd like to change the block content in the different pages.
How can I do it?
[image: Page Layout]

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are asking. Blocks are appearing in pages. Could you give further details? There are multiple options to set custom theming in Drupal pages/blocks/views etc but we need to find out what you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom header for some pages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246063/custom-header-for-some-pages)

Comment: i deleted the old question

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement this. Either by creating a new content type landing pages and set a specific template file only for this content type (I think this is the most strait forward option), or you can create a view with multiple pages (if you want to work with views) and again create a specific template for the view. Also I think that you could use the [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module and create your landing page with custom layout.